# Multiplicate two binary numbers in turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

I am trying to write the multiplication of two binary numbers using turing machine. I tried to copy the multiplier, and after each addition, subtract 1 from it (for example 110*110 = 110 + 110 // 110 - 001 and further to the second iteration). 
But I think that there is a much simpler algorithm to do that that I can’t find.
If it is important I use [this simulator](http://morphett.info/turing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use offsets.
The operation 110 * 110 is equal to the sum of 110 * 100 + 110 * 10.

Say your implementation sets the parameters' length to 3 bits; prepare the result's space (6 bits at most). Then loop over one parameter's bits and, if they're 1, add the second parameter to your result, with the corresponding offset.

Your read your first parameter's first bit, it is 0, you write nothing and your result remains 000000.

You read the second bit, it is 1. You add your second parameter to your result, with an offset of 1, so it is 110 but written one bit to the left, your result is then 00**110**0.

You read the third bit, it is 1 too. You add your second parameter to your result again, this time with an offset of 2, so it is 110 shifted two bits to the left. Your result becomes 001100 + 0**110**00 = 100100.

Comment: There's a binary multiplication example on the very website. [My own](https://codeshare.io/aYXVp3) is godawful but somehow faster, only using 0 and 1 and cleaning the result. I have obfuscated it some more since I'd believe you're asking for help with a school exercise, but seeing the execution on large numbers should let you understand the workings of it.